# git mktag - invalid tag signature file

Tags: git

Creating a tag with [git mktag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktag) output - invalid tag signature file

**The command:**

```
$ git mktag <ss >dd
```

**ss - input file:**

```
object 70b744ec08d09e2c8f5a0ba577ee6a9d3cc5d7a7
type commit
tag 11111
tagger Bob Bubbins <bob.mrbob@mail.com> 26-Mar-21 06:18:54 PM

New tag
```

**dd - output file**

**ERORR:**

> error: char47: could not find "\ntype " fatal: invalid tag signature file

What is this error?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  This looks like it might be a problem due to Windows using two characters to indicate line endings.  It seems that the second of those characters is being taken as the first character of the "type" field label in the input.  Since "\ntype" is not the same as "type", you're getting the error you are seeing.  This is just a guess from what I see.

Comment: @CryptoFool On windows, this maybe the reason. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you resave the file "ss" to have Linux line endings?

Comment: @CryptoFool did the trick, thank you. you can post the answer I'll accept

Comment: Great.  Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Windows? This looks like it might be a problem due to Windows using two characters to indicate line endings. It seems that the second of those characters is being taken as the first character of the "type" field label in the input. Since "\ntype" is not the same as "type", you're getting the error you are seeing.

I would suggest that you try resaving the file "ss" to have Linux-style line endings.